# WebView Android APP run in Background

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I have an app, i want to open a webview. right now i am loading the webview in most simple way. i would like to load the webpage in the background so the user will not have to wait.maybe in a service running in the background or in a prevoius activity i looked around the forums and could not find a refrence to the subject help will be appriciated. Thx

```
public class YTPlay extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ytplay);

        browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        browser.loadUrl("http://www.yt-play.com/app.php");

    }

}
```

Sorry my english..

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to perform any action in the background either you have to use service as in the link

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm
```

or use AsyncTask...
As ur requirement involves interaction with UI(browser) maybe its not possible todo in background as per my knowledge..